# How to send search query using opensearch and Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have an opensearch description and am supposed to send my queries using that programmatically. Unfortunately, I'm really new to all of this- are there any examples out there using Lucene and Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know nothing about `OpenSearch` but I can give you some hints of `Lucene`. To make `Lucene` search you have to first make a `Lucene` index of your data (text files, xml files, database, etc..).

There are a lot of example how to use `Lucene` all over the internet. [This](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/sample-apps/textfileindexer-java.html) looks quite good example how to make a `Lucene` index.

[This](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) covers all: indexing, searching and displaying result (It is very simple example). Because your question is not very specific, this is as I can help. If you'll have a specific problem, I would be happy to help.